# Specify Repository Path in Windows for SSH and Git

Tags: git, ssh, path

How do we specify git repo path in Windows 10?

I would like to sync the git repositories between a local Mac/Linux machine with a remote Windows 10.  Due to the safety and security concern, I am not allow to directly use git and SSH-key to connect to the Windows.  I need to build an SSH connection with ProxyCommand and apply SSH port forwarding before calling git.

The port forwarding works fine

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="JumperServer %h %p" -L 1922:localhost:22 username@$IP -N
```

```
git push -f "ssh://User@[localhost:1922]C/Users/User/Desktop/git_repo_dir"
```

My problem is the above line returns me the following error

```
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:1922 ([::1]:1922)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:vjA1nhxr9wGUEm53EA3JU4OfNJ04Co+Q1UCf2fb0q2g.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:1922' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
User@localhost's password:
'git-receive-pack' ���O�����Υ~���R�O�B�i��檺�{���Χ妸�ɡC
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I suspect the error is due to the wrong repo path syntax.  I had several tries such as following but all of them return me identical error as the above.

- git -C . push -f 'ssh://User@localhost:1922/C:\Users\User\Desktop\git_repo_dir'
- git -C . push -f 'ssh://User@localhost:1922/c:\Users\User\Desktop\git_repo_dir'
- git -C . push -f ssh://User@localhost:1922/C/Users/User/Desktop/git_repo_dir
- git -C . push -f 'ssh://User@[localhost:1922]c/Users/User/Desktop/git_repo_dir/

The whole code works when my remote machine is a Mac.  This leads me believe my problem is due to Windows path syntax.  I'm not sure about the garbled code in the error message.
The same garbled code appears both on my local Mac and Linux.

How do I solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first test is to check if a regular SSH `ls` command would work.

The syntax should be:

```
ssh User@[localhost:1922]/c/Users/User/Desktop/git_repo_dir
```

Once that is working, then you can try `git push`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried your suggestion.  
The ssh commands returns me error

gnubby-ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:1922

If I changed the path syntax in my whole code.  I got the identical error as my original post.

Comment: @vincentryanlai So my point is: keep trying different syntaxes from the `ssh ls` command: it needs to work first, then you can check your whole code. Add `ssh -Tvvv ...` to see more details.